# Mysql query and find if value exist

Tags: php, mysql

I got this code to compare and find differences between 2 CSV files (with 1 column each and 1 EAN code per line) with array_diff in both direction:

```
<?php 
mysql_connect('LOCALHOST', 'db', 'passwd') or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error()); 

$update_table = "ps_product"; 

$file1 = file('1.csv');
$file2 = file('2.csv');


$diff  =  array_diff($file1, $file2);
$diff2  = array_diff($file2, $file1);


$diffjoined = array_merge($diff, $diff2);

?>
```

Now I have to know if in the merged array, there are corresponding values inside the db and then set quantity to 0:

```
    If "a value inside array ($diffjoined) was found in DB"
  foreach "ean code found in DB"

mysql_query ("UPDATE $update_table SET quantity='0' WHERE ean13 IN ($diffjoined) ");
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: please share an example of one of your csv files.  the first 2 lines should be good.

Comment: @hofan41 My question is how to verify if there are same values (ean codes) inside the array merged, corresponding to DB, and when found, update it to 0 quantity.

Comment: @AlanAsher 1.csv: 0000000001
0000000002
0000000003
0000000004
0000000007
file2.csv:
0000000001
0000000003
0000000005
0000000004
0000000007 1 column, and 1 code per line for both files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your `$diffjoined` is a list of ean13's from your code.

Your SQL query is close

```
$eans = "'".implode("','", $diffjoined)."'";
$q = "UPDATE $update_table SET quantity='0' WHERE ean13 IN ($eans)";
mysql_query($q);
```

Comment: Ok thank you! But does it make a verification if the ean to update, is already present in DB before update ?

Comment: MySQL will only update the rows that match, so if you have eans = 1, 3,5,6 and only have 5 and 6 in your database, only 5 and 6 will get updated.

Comment: I don't know why, but no update is done. The list of ean codes show up correctly. What could be the problem ?